# The equivalent of "ip dhcp snooping information option allow-untrusted" on NX-OS

Tags: dhcp-snooping, nx-os

I'm adding DHCP Snooping to the core switches but I'm unable to find the equivalent of `ip dhcp snooping information option allow-untrusted` from Cisco IOS in Cisco NX-OS.

I've done some tests without this option and my packages are dropped on the core, so I'm guessing this may be the issue. For VLANs that does not leaves the core DHCP snooping appears to be working.

According to Cisco documentation the only options available are pretty basic: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/security/7x/b_Cisco_n3k_Security_Config_7x/b_Cisco_n3k_Security_Config_7x_chapter_01000.html

I'm running a little old version of NX-OS 7.0 on Nexus 3048.

```
Software
  BIOS: version 4.0.0
  NXOS: version 7.0(3)I4(6)
  BIOS compile time:  12/05/2016
  NXOS image file is: bootflash:///nxos.7.0.3.I4.6.bin
  NXOS compile time:  3/9/2017 22:00:00 [03/10/2017 07:05:18]
```

So is this option necessary/available on NX-OS? Is there an equivalent option?

Comment: Are you enabling DHCP snooping on the core? You should enable it on the access switches, not core switches. It should be enabled where the untrusted end-devices connect on the access switches.

Comment: Yes. I want to enable this because the routing and DHCP relay is done on the firewall, and its plugged on the core. There's no L3 routing on the access layer, so I tough it was a good idea to enable it on the core, so I can have a snooping table working on the core too because it's handy. We don't have a distribution layer.

Comment: You do not connect untrusted end-devices into the core, so you do not run DHCP snooping on the core. You run DHCP snooping on the access switches, which is where you connect untrusted end-devices, and you mark the uplink interfaces on the access switches as trusted because that is the direction of the DHCP servers. You trust the server connections, not the end-device connections.

Comment: Ok, the best practices always have some exceptions. Here the virtualization infrastructure is plugged directly on the core. The DHCP server is on a VM running in this infrastructure. We have a container platform running inside the VMs. So when an developer fires up an DHCP server for accident in a container my core will be dead. You may say that I should put an access switch on the VM platform as a best practice, but we don't have it. I'm just bringing one case, that probably will not happen, but as an example of why I want to turn on the feature in the core.

Comment: Doing it the way you do also opens yourself up to other serious problems that the end-users can create on your network, such as spanning tree loops that can kill the network with broadcast storms. This is a best practice that should not be ignored.

Comment: BPDU protection is in place on the core and working. I know that best practices should be followed always, but sometimes you don't have the money to do this. We are a public university from a developing country, this is what we got. I'm just trying to reduce the attack surface with what I got. The switch should support proper execution of DHCP snooping, and that's why I opened the question in first place.

Comment: BPDUs do not extend beyond the next interface, while broadcasts can be bridged across multiple links. As a user on that core using a VM I could easily create a broadcast storm.

Comment: In any case, there are also other problems that end-users can create on a core.

Comment: I just mentioned BPDU because you cited spanning-tree. There's storm control in-place too on the hypervisor interfaces to mitigate any possible issue from a malicious user. We're in a loop here. I understand that DHCP snooping should not be enabled on the core, although I'm trying to enable it. I just opened the issue due to a apparent missing configuration. If I do have another switch for the hypervisors it may have the same issue reported on the question.

Comment: So to re-phrase this - you want to protect against a given VM (or container) becoming a DHCP server and thus have DHCP snooping turned on with said hosts on untrusted interfaces, but DHCP snooping on the N3K is dropping request packets with option-82 included?

Comment: Hi @rnxrx the VM was an example to be honest because Ron was questioning the topology and not the real issue. But yes it's a welcoming feature. I dig a little further, and this appears to be a bug. If I enable snooping on a given VLAN, all DHCP traffic just get dropped when option-82 is included, even on VLANs that snooping is disabled. At this moment I disabled snooping completely with "no ip dhcp snooping". I'm not sure what's happening. That's not my first bug with NX-OS and DHCP related issues, look: https://bit.ly/3ik8Eqi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform you're using is basically a bugware, seems like this switch was made by some trainee before doing some real (not the "unlimited-money CVDs") networking for the first time.

Entire DHCP snooping is basically useless in a scenario with deployment in the core - binding database is limited to 2000 entries and building it cannot be disabled (database is required for DAI or DHCPRELEASE protections, but could be optional and still protect against rogue DHCP servers).

The knobs you're looking for are simply missing. Just like the MAC ACLs (sic!)... And beware, that even with TCAM-carved ARP ACLs ...they can only match `any` MAC address (only IP filtering within ARP packets is possible). At least you can use `port-security` `feature` and select some interfaces ...until you hit 8000 entries limit.

Anyway, even with DHCP snooping in action, there are no logs of blocked rogue servers (even with `logging level dhcp_snoop 7`), which makes this function effectively some syntactic sugar only.

Suggested workaround: filter rogue DHCP servers by using plain ACLs.

All of this makes this switch a non-core solution.
Unfortunately it is also not too good at access perimeter, due to the hard QoS settings (CoS vs ToS/DSCP mappings and their respective trust states), missing MAC filtering and loop-protection. Not the *STP stuff, but real malicious (and every other BPDU-filtered) loops. There is only `mac address-table loop-detect port-down` on/off switch, without per-port configuration (trusted, priority!) nor MAC move thresholds configuration. There is also no traffic segmentation (good luck with private VLANs) nor VLAN translation (only for ...VXLAN).

Also keep in mind, that the CPU of this switch get's all the ARP packets from the network. And by "all" I mean exactly this - unicast, bridged data, that should remain in data-plane, are casted to control plane god knows why. You can watch them in tcpdump from `run bash` or directly via `ethanalyzer local interface inband`... or by `show policy-map interface control-plane class copp-s-arp`. That's right, 200 pps of ARPs in entire network (with CoPP maximum about 6700 pps) makes your switch unavailable on it's in-band management interface during some ARP storm in **any** VLAN bridged (and not L3-terminated on the switch). Unless you craft separate CoPP rule (there are 4 slots available, hooray!) to handle ARPs that are really destined to the CPU, which seems to be another must-have for n3k in the core.

Update:
There is one more important thing to know about DHCP snooping operation. In contrary to other devices, which block untrusted responses (i.e. OFFER, ACK, NAK), this switch apparently doesn't forward client requests (DISCOVER, REQUEST) to untrusted ports, so the rogue servers have nothing to reply to. As fas as this might seem clever, there are consequences. First, mentioned above - there are no logs of such servers. Second - owner of any misconnected device doesn't see too much devices requesting addresses and eventual resource starvation. This is the next reason to block offending DHCP by using plain ACLs - one could attach some diagnostic box and pass everything to it, before blocking DHCP globally. This is especially important on networks with clients terminated on dumb switches, where the DHCP snooping won't prevent mess in a zone behind a single port.